# Subquery inside JOIN leads to seq scan

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use a subquery as a join table to perform some aggregation work:

```
SELECT r.source_uri       AS su_on_r,
       c_on_tComposer
FROM   release r
       LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT track, string_agg(distinct composer, '|') as c_on_tComposer
             FROM track_composer
             GROUP BY track
       ) tComposer ON r.id = tComposer.track
```

The reason I do this in a subquery is that if I simply join the `track_composer` table and then perform the aggregation in the `SELECT` I have duplicate data when other 1:M tables (not shown here) are joined. If I use a subquery join table with the aggregation inside, I can assure that one row is always returned, reducing data duplication.

Trouble is, the query planner in Postgresql tries to do a seq scan on the `track_composer` table:

```
->  Materialize  (cost=3567796.15..3806217.09 rows=2988177 width=48) (actual time=20629.349..76646.074 rows=12998764 loops=1)          
      ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=3567796.15..3768864.88 rows=2988177 width=48) (actual time=20629.342..70072.823 rows=12996153 loops=1) 
            Group Key: track_composer.track                                                                                            
            ->  Sort  (cost=3567796.15..3622368.32 rows=21828868 width=30) (actual time=20629.309..36473.835 rows=21778170 loops=1)    
                  Sort Key: track_composer.track                                                                                       
                  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 864192kB                                                                          
                  ->  Seq Scan on track_composer  (cost=0.00..384612.68 rows=21828868 width=30) (actual time=0.041..5085.321 rows=21828
```

I have an index on `track_composer.track`.

It looks like this is done because of the `GROUP BY` but I require this because of the `string_agg` aggregation. Am I going about this incorrectly, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a sequential scan, try defining an index on `(track, composer)`:

```
create index idx_track_composer_track_composer on track_composer(track, composer);
```

This is called a composite index -- a fancy way of saying that it has more than one key.

I have had good luck in other databases using correlated subqueries in this case:

```
SELECT r.source_uri AS su_on_r,
       (SELECT string_agg(distinct composer, '|') as c_on_tComposer
        FROM track_composer tc
        WHERE r.id = tc.track
       ) as c_on_tComposer
FROM release r;
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `(track, composer)`? There is already an index on `track_composer.track`.

Comment: Oh ok, you mean a composite? I figured that because only the `track` column is named, that's all that matters. Will try this select now...

Comment: That move to the select statement works a beauty, thanks, will accept when SO lets me...

Comment: What to do when the subquery needs to return more than one column?

Comment: @DanGravell . . . You can use a lateral join instead.